# Array elements x axis actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a text field array as the array elements has a different width sizes.. I want to add it to the stage as one line without spaces.. So.. how to set the x axis?

here's the code:

```
var _objects:Array = new Array();
var rowCount:uint = 114;
for (var o:uint = 0; o<114; o++)
{
    var label_txt:TextField = drawTxt();
    _objects.push(label_txt);
    label_txt.y = 10
    label_txt.x = (o % rowCount) * (_objects[o].width);// this code gives me 100 px on x for each element.

    addChild(label_txt);
}
```

MORE DETAILS

text field:

```
function drawTxt():TextField
{
    var label_txt:TextField = new TextField();
    label_txt.border = true;
    label_txt.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
    label_txt.selectable = false;
    label_txt.multiline = false;
    label_txt.defaultTextFormat = myFormatBold;
    return label_txt;
}
```

text data (xml):

```
function arrayzeLabelsXML():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < xmlLabelsData.item.length(); i++)
    {
        attributeLabelsContent.push(xmlLabelsData.item[i].@item);
        translateContent.push(xmlLabelsData.item[i].@translate);

        nodeLabelsContent.push(xmlLabelsData.item[i]);
        nodeContent.push(xmlLabelsData.translate[i]);

        _objects[i].text = nodeLabelsContent[i];
        _objects[i].width = _objects[i].textWidth + 20;
        _objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler);

    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.add textFields,only set y value

```
var _objects:Array = [];
var rowCount:uint = 114;
var currentX:Number = 0;
for (var o:uint = 0; o<rowCount; o++)
{
    var label_txt:TextField = drawTxt();
    _objects.push(label_txt);
    label_txt.y = 10
    addChild(label_txt);
}
```

2.set text to the textField, the reason why you got textWidth equal to 0 is you haven't set text to them.

```
arrayzeLabelsXML();
```

3.to set x values

```
  var currentX:Number = 0;

  var gap:Number = 0;

   for (var o:uint = 0; o<rowCount; o++)
   {
       var label_txt:TextField = _objects[i] as TextField;
       if ( label_txt) {
           label_txt.x = currentX + gap;//if you find the textField overlap,try to set a bigger gap.
           currentX += label_txt.textWidth;
       }

   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much solved.. thank you all Pan , Sunil and Gaston.

Comment: var label_txt:TextField = _objects[i] as TextField;
  if ( label_txt)
  {
   label_txt.x = currentX;
   currentX += label_txt.textWidth + 20;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `TextField` class has [textWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#textWidth) and [textHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#textHeight) properties. These are the actual width/height of the text as opposed to the width/height of the `DisplayObject` that contains the text.

**NOTE**: The [documentation says](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html) the default size of a `TextField` is 100x100, so the `width` may not always equal the `textWidth` (which I assume is the case here).

Since you say you want to arrange them in a line w/no space, I would also use an algorithm like this:

```
var _objects:Array = [];
var rowCount:uint = 114;
var currentX:Number = 0;
for (var o:uint = 0; o<114; o++)
{
    var label_txt:TextField = drawTxt();
    _objects.push(label_txt);
    label_txt.y = 10
    label_txt.x = currentX;
    currentX = currentX + label_txt.textWidth;
    addChild(label_txt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually it doesn't work! the returned value is 0

Comment: Maybe you should show more code. If I simply do `var tf:TextField = new TextField(); tf.text="woot"; trace(tf.textWidth);` the output is "24.1". Maybe you should edit your question to show what is happening in `drawTxt()`.

Comment: the text fields width is correct my problem only with the x axis

Comment: Now I completely don't understand what you're trying to do :) When you said the textWidth is 0, it was because you checked the `textWidth` when the `TextField` didn't have any text. You also don't show how you're using the `arrayzeLabelsXML()` method. And I don't understand what you mean that the problem is only with the X axis.

Comment: Finally, have you looked at my algorithm where I track the `currentX` value, and use that to set each labels width? Your algorithm doesn't seem right. For example, on the third iteration (where i=2) you would set the X coordinate = 2%100 * object[2].width which means 2*width, on iteration 3 you would set X to 3*width, and so on. Is that what you mean by problem w/the X axis?

Comment: @Nezarov Me too, I don't understand, Can you post a image to see which is the space that appear between the text? Maybe we can give you more choices to solve this.

Comment: for example I have 4 textFields stored inside the array.. each one has a different width size (60 40 70 130) I want to add them to the stage, but before that I want to set the x axis for each one to get one line without spaces between the text fields.